# How to achieve locking across multiple table updates in Cassandra so as to attain isolation and avoid dirty read probem

Tags: cassandra, transactions, nosql, cassandra-3.0, consistency

I am using Cassandra as a NoSQL DB in my solution and have a Data model  wherein I have 2 tables , one is parent table and other one is child table

Here is the scenario

1. client A is trying to update a parent table record as well child table records
2. At the same time,  client B also does select request (which makes a hit to both parent and child table)
3. client B receives latest record from Parent table but gets older record from Child table

***I can use a batch log operation so that I can achieve atomicity for updating both the tables but not sure how to isolate or lock the read request from Client B so as to avoid having dirty read problem.*
*Have also tried evaluating light weight transactions but doesnt seem to work in this case***

Just thinking if I can use some middleware application to implement locking functionality since there seems to be nothing available in Cassandra out of the box.

Please help to make me understand how to achieve read/write sync in this regard

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned - Cassandra provides only atomicity when you *choose to batch*. It does provide isolation though when you make a single partition batch, which is not your case unfortunately.

To respond to your question - if you really need transaction I would think about the problem and possible solutions once again. Either you should eliminate the need of locking or you should change the technology stack.